# Does migrating data from SQL Server to SQLite have effects on the application codes

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, sqlite

I have a project I developed with C# windows forms using SQL Server as database but I want to make the project standalone without any database server. I found SQLite as an option to go for, Is it possible to migrate my SQL Server database to SQLite and not affecting my code? And how do I go about it?

I used entityframework code first in connecting the SQL Server database

Comment: Perhaps you could show us some of your code that interacts with the database?

Comment: Have you considered using SQL Server Express?

Comment: Depends on the code. For example, right outer join and full outer join isn't present in sqlite.

Comment: @mjwills SQL Server Express requires me to have a database engine

Comment: I want something that does not need me to have a database engine, maybe that's not the right word to use but I want to be able to install on other machine and run without worrying about the machine having the database or not..
Completely offline

Comment: You have to use a wrapper to use SQLite from managed code. Have a look at [System.Data.SQLite](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is almost certainly going to be "yes." Depending on a few things, you might have to change very little (or no) code, or you might have to change a lot.

The first consideration is your SQL code. If you were very careful to write ANSI-compliant SQL and you didn't use any of the built-in SQL Server views or T-SQL-specific functions, you may not have to re-write much code at all. In reality, you probably will have to at least write some. In particular, while SQL Server's engine is meant to handle multiple concurrent sessions and queries, SQLite is not: you will need to manage your program carefully to ensure no two threads attempt to access the SQLite database at once.

The second consideration is how your application calls the database. Again, depending on your design, you may need to re-write almost no code, or you may need to re-write a lot. In my C# applications, I create an interface for database providers that defines common functionality (select, delete, insert, etc). Then I create simple wrapper classes for different RDBMS that implement the interface. When I need to switch databases, I simply instantiate and use a different class. If you have your project setup like this, then you'd simply need to create a new class for SQLite that implements your database interface and instantiate that instead of your SQL Server class. If you wrote a lot of SQL Server specific C# code into your business logic, you might have a lot of coding to do.